Weight paint not assigned to correct mesh on right side, only on left side of the object
I have been stuck with this issue for a while now and cannot seem to find a solution.
I have a model that i am trying to parent with the armature but the end result is completely different from right and left hands regarding weight paint. Any idea what i am doing wrong?


Hello, so you've tried to parent With Automatic Weight and this is the result? Maybe you have no other choice but to correct in Weight Paint mode...

Hi @moonboots, thanks for the feedback. I undertsnd that but i would really like to know why does this behaviour happen? Any idea?

Could you please share your file so that we can give a try? Parenting With Automatic Weights doesn't always give the best result, especially with hands, where faces are pretty  close to each others
